# JAVA-Como retornar valores de un for,cuando estos valores que debo mostrar son los valores del int i=1,2,3,etc?

Tags: java, poo

EJERCICIO JAVA:Incorpora el método contarDivisores en la clase Calculadora. Éste método debe recibir el siguiente parámetro: a. numero: int 
El método debe devolver todos los números enteros que sean divisores del número recibido por parámetro.

esa es la pregutna en cuestion,no tengo idea por donde encararla,pense en lo basico pero no funciono,ya que no se como retornar el valor del i en cuestion que es lo que necesito,desde le mismo metodo:

```
public int contarDivisores(int numero){
            int resultado=0;
            int q=1;
            if(numero%q==0){
                resultado=1;
            for( q=1;q<=numero;q++){


                resultado=q;

                }

        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: El enunciado te pide que devuelva todos los valores. Un método solo puede devolver una sola cosa, por lo tanto debes de crear un Array y guardar los divisores en el y devolver el array.

Comment: era lo que pensaba,muchas gracias ,consultare con el profesor sobre eso

Comment: Primero debes recorrer todos los números con el FOR y luego con el IF evaluar si es divisor. En el código lo tienes al revés.
Sería algo así:

for(q=1;q<=numero;q++){
if(numero%q){/*Tu codigo*/}
}↓

Comment: gracias yors,eso lo habia hecho al inicio,mande el codigo luego de toquetearlo y cansarme de intentar,pero por lo que veo,por fdefinicion un metodo solo puede retornar UNA COSA,entonces deberia crear un array y que me retorne ese array(que adentro tendra varias cosas).el tema es que en clase aun no me lo explicaron y no queria hacerlo de esa manera.

Comment: Tengo el código, si lo quieres te lo pongo en respuesta para que tengas una referencia. El problema que tienes en que un Array NO puede cambiar el tamaño en JAVA. De hecho en JAVA se usan Listas.

Comment: desconozco esa parte de esa teoria,pero me encantaria tener tu referencia .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

He creado una clase para probar el código. He mantenido el array de int que retorna

```
public class Divisores {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int num=500;

        Divisores div=new Divisores();
        int[] divisores= div.contarDivisores(num);
            System.out.println("Divisores de "+ num + " ("+divisores.length+" divisores encontrados) ");

        for(int j=0; j<divisores.length;j++)
            System.out.println(divisores[j]);


    }



    public  int[] contarDivisores(int numero){

String s="";     
  int q=1;
        for( q=1;q<=numero;q++){
            if(numero%q==0){
                s+=q+";";  
            }
    }

 String[] lista= s.split(";");
 int li=lista.length;
 int[] resultado=new int[li];
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<li;i++)
     resultado[i]=Integer.parseInt(lista[i]);


 return resultado;
}

}
```

Comment: impecable,aun que no entiendo algunas lineas del codigo con el conocimiento que tengo hasta ahora,pero valoro mucho tu respuesta,me ha orientado!

Comment: Me imagino que desconoces la funcion split. Si te fijas rdevuelve un array de String a partir de un String delimitado por un separador( en este caso el puntoycoma ";").
Como un array de String de no nos sirve hay que convertilo a un array de in utilizando el método Interger.parseInt